# Почему такая реализация меню в libGDX не работает?

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

Пытаюсь реализовать меню, который работает следующим образом. Нажимаем на MenuMainPage переходим на MenuFirstPage, нажимаем на MenuFirstPage и переходим на MenuSecondPage, нажимаем на MenuSecondPage переходим обратно на MenuMainPage и так до бесконечности. Но когда перехожу с MenuFirstPage на MenuSecondPage выдает ошибку, хотя с MenuMainPage на MenuFirstPage переходит без проблем. Не понимаю, то ли код неверно написал, что JRE его не воспринимает, то ли с JRE какие-то проблемы (хотя АндроидСтудио обновил, поставил новый OpenJDK 13.0.2).

```
public class MainGame extends Game {
  @Override
  public void create() {
    setScreen(new MenuMainPage(this));
  }
}

public class MenuMainPage implements Screen {
  public SpriteBatch batch;
  public BitmapFont font;
  public MainGame game;

  public MenuMainPage(MainGame game){
    this.game = game;
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    font = new BitmapFont();
  }

  @Override
  public void show() {

  }
  @Override
  public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    font.draw(batch, "MenuMainPage", 30,30);
    if(Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        game.setScreen(new MenuFirstPage(game));
    }
    batch.end();
  }
  @Override
  public void resize(int width, int height) {

  }
  @Override
  public void pause() {

  }
  @Override
  public void resume() {

  }
  @Override
  public void hide() {
    dispose();
  }
  @Override
  public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    font.dispose();
  }
}

public class MenuFirstPage implements Screen {
  public SpriteBatch batch;
  public BitmapFont font;
  public MainGame game;

  public MenuFirstPage(MainGame game){
    this.game = game;
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    font = new BitmapFont();
  }

  @Override
  public void show() {

  }
  @Override
  public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    font.draw(batch, "MenuFirstPage", 30,30);
    if(Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        game.setScreen(new MenuSecondPage(game));
    }
    batch.end();
  }
  @Override
  public void resize(int width, int height) {

  }
  @Override
  public void pause() {

  }
  @Override
  public void resume() {

  }
  @Override
  public void hide() {
    dispose();
  }
  @Override
  public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    font.dispose();
  }
}

public class MenuSecondPage  implements Screen {
  public SpriteBatch batch;
  public BitmapFont font;
  public MainGame game;

  public MenuSecondPage(MainGame game) {
    this.game = game;
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    font = new BitmapFont();
  }

  @Override
  public void show() {

  }

  @Override
  public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    font.draw(batch, "MenuSecondPage", 30,30);
    if(Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        game.setScreen(new MenuMainPage(game));
    }
    batch.end();
  }

  @Override
  public void resize(int width, int height) {

  }

  @Override
  public void pause() {

  }

  @Override
  public void resume() {

  }

  @Override
  public void hide() {
    dispose();
  }

  @Override
  public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    font.dispose();
  }
}

public class DesktopLauncher {
  public static void main (String[] arg) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    new LwjglApplication(new MainGame(), config);
  }
}
```

А выхлоп дает такой:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffc11f9d17e, pid=3144, tid=0x0000000000002864
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_212-b04) (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.212-b04 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x3d17e]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Android\LibGDXProjects\ExpMenu\hs_err_pid3144.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

[error occurred during error reporting , id 0xc0000005]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

P.S. Проверил код на другом компьютере, выдает такую же ошибку.

Comment: Можешь полностью выложить код классов MenuFirstPage и MenuSecondPage?

Comment: Код полностью выглядит так)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо перенести код перехода на новый экран ниже batch.end():

```
...
batch.end();
if(Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
    game.setScreen(new MenuFirstPage(game));
}
```

Comment: Заработало! Спасибо Вам большое! А то сижу со вчерашнего дня с этим вопросом:)))